# Sort Swift Code

Tags: swift

Who has idea of why this is occurring?

It is giving me error at the `Array(places).sorted { $0.1 < $1.1 }.map { $0.0 }` part.

```
let placesByBeacons = [
    "12103:16951": [
        "Heavenly Sandwiches": 5, // read as: it's 5 meters from
        // "Heavenly Sandwiches" to the beacon with
        // major 6574 and minor 54631
        "Green & Green Salads": 10,
        "Mini Panini": 15
    ],
    "648:12": [
        "Heavenly Sandwiches": 250,
        "Green & Green Salads": 100,
        "Mini Panini": 20
    ],
    "17581:4351": [
        "Heavenly Sandwiches": 350,
        "Green & Green Salads": 500,
        "Mini Panini": 170
    ]
]

func placesNearBeacon(beacon: CLBeacon) -> [String]? {
    let beaconKey = "\(beacon.major):\(beacon.minor)"
    if let places = self.placesByBeacons[beaconKey] {
        let sortedPlaces = Array(places).sorted { $0.1 < $1.1 }.map { $0.0 }
        return sortedPlaces
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: `sorted` -> `sort`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `sort` not `sorted`. You can also make your function shorter:

```
func placesNearBeacon(beacon: CLBeacon) -> [String]? {
    guard let places = placesByBeacons["\(beacon.major):\(beacon.minor)"] else { return nil }
    return places.sort(<).map { $0.0 }
}
```

Comment: Would `.sort(<)` really work on an an array of tuples though?